# Configuración Service Provider

Tags: java, webservice

Buenas gente,

Estoy configurando un **Service Provider** en Java que se comunique con un **IdP** pasándole un String para que este lo valide. El protocolo de comunicación entre ambos debe ser **SAML**. Nunca había hecho esto así que estoy un poco perdido y estoy haciendo pruebas.

El código de mi clase es el siguiente:

```
    DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();

    // Request
    final AuthnRequest ar = createAuthNRequest(urlSP, urlIdP);
    final String arString = samlToString(ar);

    // Element para el request
    final Element req = getElementFromString(arString);

    // Element para el header
    final SOAPElement headerElem = createHeader(prefijo, uri, miString);

    final MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    final SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
    final SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    final SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

    // Header
    final SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
    header.addChildElement(headerElem);

    // Body
    final SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
    body.addDocument(((Node) req).getOwnerDocument());

    message.saveChanges();
    final SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    final SOAPConnection sc = scf.createConnection();
    final SOAPMessage resp = sc.call(message, urlIdP);
```

Como se puede ver simplemente me creo un **Element** para el *header* y el *body* de un **SOAPMessage**. En el *body* meto el **AuthnRequest** y en el *header* el String que quiero que el IdP me valide. El código de los métodos a los que se llama no los pongo por no engordar mucho el mensaje, pero si son relevantes decídmelo y los pongo.

El xml que se manda en el **sc.call** es el siguiente:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">miString</wsse:Username>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="http://idp.seg.um:8080" ID="_45c45694c107cdf75164305f2231cb76" IssueInstant="2016-07-22T06:30:48.230Z" Version="2.0">
        <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">http://sp.seg.um:8080</saml2:Issuer>
    </saml2p:AuthnRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Con esto sería suficiente? Lo pregunto porque he visto en muchos sitios que se crean .xsd, .wsdl....pero como es algo tan tonto (o eso parece) no me he complicado mucho la vida la verdad.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!